# Node mysql in Discord.js returns empty result/array

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that get the selected queries from a table where the id is the one i use in the command, for example: ***!db 1*** but I'm having a problem.
The problem is that the result is empty.

My code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, connection) => {
    const asd = args.slice(1,2).join(' ');

    let querystring = `SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = '${asd}'`

    connection.query(querystring, function (err, results, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(results);
    });

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "db"
}
```

I  appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: is id a string in your db?

Comment: Please include some more information about the table in your database, since there is not much we can do with the information you've provided

Comment: @Caltrop is that - https://imgur.com/a/go67JmA what you needed as an information? let me know if you need more info about the tables. (that's a screenshot from HeidiSql, also it's on bulgarian, sorry.

Comment: I meant a VARCHAR. In your code, you are wrapping `${asd}` with singlequotes, so I assume it's trying  to match your value as a VARCHAR

Comment: @AyushGupta No, id is INT, I also tried replacing the column `WHERE id` with `WHERE membername` but still shows `[]` as a result...

Comment: Tbh I've tried everything... by everything I mean that I've been struggling with this db thing for 3/4 days now... Idk what to do to make it work the way I want...

Answer (score 1):

[From the screenshot you posted earlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIFWx.jpg), your `id` column is a type `INT`. This code is searching as if the column is a `VARCHAR`.

Try this:

```js
const id = args.slice(1, 2).join(' ');
if (isNaN(id)) { return; } // if the input isn't a number
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ${Number.parseInt(id)}`, (err, res, rows) => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

**Important**: This code allows [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Template literals **do not** protect against this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get this error:
`Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @ИвайлоМ. you should avoid executing the query if the supplied value isn't a number. For example, I've updated my answer to have an `isNaN()` check before the query.

Comment: Still getting the same error :/ Idk why I even get the error in 1st place... I use the command `!db 3` which means the console should result the row that contains `3` in `id` column. Even tried replacing `${Number.parseInt(id)}` with `${Number.isInteger(id)}` but then I get `[]` as a result...